# preconditioner for least square -RIF

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

Reference:
[https://www.cs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/copper.pdf](https://www.cs.emory.edu/%7Ebenzi/Web_papers/copper.pdf)

I am interested in building a RIF preconditioner for least square problem based on the C-orthogonalization in the above paper:
start with e1-en (cols of identity matrix), using conjugate Gram–Schmidt process with inner product
<u,v>_c = u^T @ C @ v = u^T @ A^T @ A @ v, then apply some dropping strategy to get a sparse incomplete decomposition.

I have no experience to work directly on the sparse matrix using scipy. Anyone could provide some similar code sample?

Thanks.

Related algorithms:
[algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ibdq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not know which format of sparse matrix to use to create the sparse upper triangular Z matrix in the algorithm link (step 1,7,10) at the bottom, lil_matrix or csr_matrix or other formats. I did some research on the scipy sparse matrix and still could not figure it out. The number of nonzero entries in each row cannot be predetermined.